# While Loop in FPDF only prints 1 result

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, fpdf

i'm having a problem with FPDF, i want to create a While Loop that returns every result that my SQL query does when i use Phpmyadmin, the problem here is that it only returns one. If i use
$pdf->Cell(190,10,''.$pdf_info2['format'].'',1,1,0);
it does print the result i want, but i need to return them in the table as i show below.
Ps: This is my firts question so i appolagise if i wasn't that clear o my problem. 
Thanks in advance

```
$html='<table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">Tipo</td>
                <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">Formato</td>
                <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">Pago</td>
                <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">Editar</td>
            </tr>';
            while($pdf_info2 = $smth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $html2 = '<tr>
<td width="150" height="40"   bgcolor="#e6e6e6">'.$pdf_info['format'].'</td>
                <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">.$pdf_info['format'].</td>
                <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">.$pdf_info['format'].</td>
                <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">.$pdf_info['format'].</td>
                <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">.$pdf_info['format'].</td>
            </tr>';
            }

$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$pdf->WriteHTML($html2);
```

Comment: `$html2 .= ` See that dot in front of `=`?

Comment: And `$pdf_info['format']` should be `$pdf_info2['format']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

First you must need to define before loop: `$html2 = '';` and concatenate with `$html2 .=` in while loop see below code for updated code:

```
$html2 ='';
$html ='<table border="0">
<tr>
    <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">Tipo</td>
    <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">Formato</td>
    <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">Pago</td>
    <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">Editar</td>
</tr>';

while($pdf_info2 = $smth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $html2 .='<tr>
        <td width="150" height="40"   bgcolor="#e6e6e6">'.$pdf_info2['format'].'</td>
        <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">'.$pdf_info2['format'].'</td>
        <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">'.$pdf_info2['format'].'</td>
        <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">'.$pdf_info2['format'].'</td>
        <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">'.$pdf_info2['format'].'</td>
    </tr>';
}

$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$pdf->WriteHTML($html2);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, i'm going to mark it as correct when i can, in 10 minutes, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**Option1.**first you need to merger data with previous data so use  `$html .= $html;`

**Option2** update   $pdf_info

to

```
$pdf_info2
```

and no need to use 2 `$pdf->WriteHTML();`

so total code will be

```
$html='<table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">Tipo</td>
                <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">Formato</td>
                <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">Pago</td>
                <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">Editar</td>
            </tr>';
            while($pdf_info2 = $smth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $html .= '<tr>
                <td width="150" height="40"   bgcolor="#e6e6e6">'.$pdf_info2['format'].'</td>
                <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">'.$pdf_info2['format'].'</td>
                <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">'.$pdf_info2['format'].'</td>
                <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">'.$pdf_info2['format'].'</td>
                <td width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#e6e6e6">'.$pdf_info2['format'].'</td>
            </tr>';
            }

$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
```